# Multiple X startup profiles

Tags: login, session, display-manager

I run XMonad window manager and use .XSession to startup things like Dropbox and launch other apps I need, at login manager i select User Defined Session. I like to know is there a login manager where I can have .XSession1, .XSession2 and .XSession3 where I have different profiles. So 1st one 'daily dev', 'just browsing' and thirdly 'offline' ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using KDM for a while, and I have a whole raft of custom login profiles.

KDM looks in `/usr/share/xsessions` for a bunch of .desktop files, which tells it what application to execute to spawn the session.

`cat /usr/share/xsessions/awesomex.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=awesomex ( Extended )
Comment=Highly configurable framework window manager
Exec=/usr/bin/awesomex
```

On my machine, `/usr/bin/awesomex` is a fully customised Xsession startup script that spawns awesomewm with a few of my own programs.

The best part of this, is KDM remembers which session I used last time, and then re-uses it each time I log-in until I decide otherwise.

( I believe other login-managers, perhaps GDM, also recognise these files, but not sure )

Comment: Nice... Off to google..